# How to increase sound over 100% on Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: 18.04, sound, ubuntu-budgie

How to increase sound over 100% in Ubuntu Budgie I know you can do it in terminal but I wanna be able to use <kbd>Super Key</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to do it. Like in regular ubuntu 18.04 you can check in settings allow sound over 100% but how to do something like that in UBuntu Budgie 18.04?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this too. I really miss being able to boost volume beyond 100% when needed! (I'm on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 as well)

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` and see if You can increase volume there.